# jqGrid: drag and drop row

Tags: jqgrid

I have 2 grids with the same models:

[my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBjR7.png)

after drop on target: dropped row columns shifted left for one column.

[drop result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVTmc.png)

and console log

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rUme.png)

Thank you

Comment: Could you prepare **the demo**, which reproduces what you do? You can get https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/52boyw5x/ or https://jsfiddle.net/52boyw5x/2/ as the starting point.

Comment: Can you please post your full code including both grids and drag and drop setup. Additionally to this it is needed to know the jqGrid version used